# Capistrano Net::SSH.start deprecating watning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, capistrano, capistrano3

Just upgraded to the latest capistrano and my rails deployments are all printing this warning -

```
/home/vivek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/sshkit-1.14.0/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `call': Passing nil, or [nil] to Net::SSH.start is deprecated for keys: user
```

Everything seems to be working.

I upgraded from 3.5.0 to the current release (3.91.). Is there anything that needs to be changed in deploy.rb?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When declaring your servers in e.g. `config/deploy/production.rb`, make sure to explicitly set a username. My guess is that you don't have one specified, hence the warning.

For example:

```
server "example.com", user: "deploy", roles: %w[app web]
```

You can test that the username is being accepted by running:

```
$ cap production doctor:servers

Servers (1)

    deploy@example.com [:app, :web]
```

The username for each server can also be overridden globally via `:ssh_options`. If you set `:ssh_options`, make sure those options don't include something like `user: nil`.

You can inspect the value of `:ssh_options` by running:

```
$ cap production doctor:variables
```

Comment: I have a user set  in my all my deploy files - server 'xxx.xxx.com', user: 'deployer', roles: [:web, :app], primary: true - still gives me the warning

Comment: @subbu are you setting `:ssh_options` anywhere? `cap production doctor:variables` can be helpful here.

Comment: I found this `:ssh_options                 {:forward_agent=>true, :user=>nil, :keys=>["~/.ssh/id_rsa"]}` - I commented that out and it seems to have gotten rid of the warning. I guess this was some unwanted code that code left behind - never caused a problem so I guess it was never removed. Much thanks! :)

Comment: I've update your original answer with info from your previous comments, and the actions I took to fix the issue - please edit/correct my edit as required. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer to include `:ssh_options`. If that solved your problem I'd appreciate an upvote/accept. Thanks!

Comment: Done, sir! Thanks so much!